# Best Approach on MS CRM Data Migration

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-4, ssis-2008

I have to migrate data from CRM 4.0 to MS CRM Online & customer has around 35GB data now my question is which would be the best way to migrate the data?

A: Using CRM 4.0 Data Migration Manager to export the data & then using import the data using ConfigurationMigration? Is that be viable solution?
B: Export the data from CRM 4.0 using Data Migration Manager & then upload it using SSIS or custom code?

Any idea how much time usual it should take to upload that much data (35GB this includes Account, Appointments, Lead & few custom entities)

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar need and extended an existing open source project to migrate (almost) all the CRM entities.

We published it here: https://github.com/marcopierobon/CrmChainsaw

We had a smaller DB to migrate (5GB) and it took around 48 hours. The main problem is the CRM endpoint that is pretty slow, so it's really difficult to make it faster.

Comment: I am downloading the project from Github but can you tell me how are you taking the data into the program?

Comment: You use the Reference Data Transporter tool to migrate the data (the tool preserves the Guid of the records, so the relationships can be recreated).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Scribe (www.scribesoft.com) and Kingswaysoft (http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm)

These companies both provide tools for migrating data into Dynamics CRM.